# SOQL Subquery counting the number of results

Tags: salesforce, soql

I'm trying to create a SOQL query that pulls records from an Object based on if there are any results from another linked object. Here is sort of what I am trying to do.

```
SELECT id, casenumber FROM case WHERE count(SELECT ContentDocumentId FROM ContentDocumentLink WHERE  LinkedEntityId = case.id) > 0
```

This returns the error,
*MALFORMED_QUERY:
casenumber FROM case WHERE count(SELECT ContentDocumentId FROM ContentDocumentLink
^
ERROR at Row:1:Column:44
unexpected token: 'SELECT'*

After a few attempts at trying to make this work I am not sure what else try. I know SOQL has some limitations but I am unsure if this is one of them. Anyone have insight? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It's "down, then up", via many to many relationship. 1 document could be linked to many Cases but wasting storage space just once.

Normally you'd try something like this

```
SELECT Id, CaseNumber, Subject
FROM Case
WHERE Id IN (SELECT LinkedEntityId FROM ContentDocumentLink)
```

But it won't compile, there are some [limitations](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/231400/entity-contentdocumentlink-is-not-supported-for-semi-join-inner-selects). Experiment, worst case query all cases and use apex to inspect the related list?

```
SELECT Id, CaseNumber, Subject, (SELECT ContentDocumentId FROM ContentDocumentLinks LIMIT 1)
FROM Case
```

Case is funny. Attachments linked to emails (if you have Email-to-Case) will show on related list of Files but they won't be physically there. The full link will be Content Document -> ContentDocumentLink -> EmailMessage -> Case. Argh. CombinedAttachment is supposed to help with it, special readonly [related list](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_combinedattachment.htm) / view / whatever.

One more idea using [polymorphic soql](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_SOQL_polymorphic_relationships.htm), bit bass-ackwards but give it a go:

```
SELECT ContentDocumentId, TYPEOF LinkedEntity WHEN Case THEN Id, Subject, CaseNumber END
FROM ContentDocumentLink
WHERE LinkedEntityId IN (SELECT Id FROM Case)
```